# Cut image before upload it?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have Laravel application, I need to upload the image profile, I'm using [Croppie-js](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/), and I need to cut the profile image before upload it so I tried this code but not working.

The images upload with full width and height!

The code of Laravel is finding and work.

> Just need to resize the image before upload it.

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="field">
   <label class="label">Profile Image</label>
   <div class="control">
   <input type="file" name="image" id="image_file" class="input" required>
   </div>
  <div id="upload-demo"></div>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
 <script>

    var resize = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
   enableOrientation: true,    
    viewport: { 
       width: 200,
       height: 200,
       type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
      width: 500,
      height: 300
    }
  }); 

   $('#image_file').on('change', function () { 
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
      resize.croppie('bind',{
       url: e.target.result
      }).then(function(){
         console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using something else instead of javascript to manipulate the images? There could be an easier way.

Comment: @zlatan Can you pls suggest to me something else?

Comment: I will give you an example in the answer, give me a minute to write it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use something else instead of javascript, I could suggest you to use [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction) package. Here's a simple example:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
   $image = $request->image; //get your image
   $resizedImage = Image::make($image); //create an instance of Image Intervention
   $residedImage->resize('x', 'y') //Resize (or use any other function) to wanted size.
   $resizedImage->save();

   //Save image to database, or do something else with it. 
   YourModel::create($resizedImage);
}
```

> **Note:** Don't forget to import the class at the top of your controller.

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want a user to select the size of your images, here's the simple solution:

Add two input fields in your HTML, where user will type in the size he wants.

```
<input type="text" name="width" class="input" required>
<input type="text" name="height" class="input" required>
```

Get the sizes in your controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {   
   $image = $request->image; //get your image
   $width = $request->input('width'); //get width
   $height = = $request->input('height'); //get height
   $resizedImage = Image::make($image); //create an instance of Image Intervention
   $residedImage->resize($width, $height) //resize 
   $resizedImage->save();

   //Save image to database, or do something else with it. 
   YourModel::create($resizedImage);  
}
```

> **Note:** Don't forget to validate user's input, so they cant' submit
>   false data.

Comment: Thank you, but I need that user to choose the width or the height of the image!

Comment: That could be done as well, pretty simple. Will update my answer.